# How to set msg.sender in web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm making a subcurrency with solidity. I'm confused at implementing the transfer mechanism.

Here's my code:

```
function SubCoin(){
      balances[msg.sender] = totalPoints;
}

function send(address to, uint256 valueInmWard) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= valueInmWard) {
      balances[to] += valueInmWard;
      balances[msg.sender] -= valueInmWard;
      PointTransfer(msg.sender, to, valueInmWard);
    }
  }
```

I'm stuck at setting the msg.sender address. I only know I can use:
 `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase;` to send from `eth.accounts[0]`. I call `SubCoin.send.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[1], 1000);` in web3 to perform the action.

If I would like to send among `eth.accounts[1]`, `eth.accounts[2]`..., how should I specify the `msg.sender` in web3?

Answer (score 6):

`sendTransaction` expects an optional transaction object as first parameter after the method arguments. Among other things this allows you to specify the sender address via the `from` attribute.

Example:

```
var tx = {from: web3.eth.accounts[1]};
SubCoin.send.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[0], 1000, tx);
```

The same transaction object can not only be passed to `contract.method.sendTransaction` but also to `contract.method.call`, `web3.eth.sendTransaction`, and `web3.eth.call`.

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction).

Comment: Hi, I'm studying DAPP. I have a question.. How can it be allowed changing msg.sender parameter from who calling api?
Is it possible on main network? I'm confused how it can be safe..

Comment: msg.sender is recovered from the transaction signature. It should only be possible to create the signature for a given address if you have the private key to that address.